# How to end useless, drawn-out technical conversations?

Tags: colleagues, productivity, teamwork

For context, I work on a software development team and I have a teammate we'll call Bob. Bob regularly comes up with ideas on how we can improve things and proposes these ideas to his teammates. In general this is great; there is always room for improvement in processes, architecture, design, etc.

The vast majority of Bob's ideas however are not good ideas. He will come up with Idea A, and within 10 seconds or so of hearing it the teammate to which he's talking can think up reasons X, Y, and Z as to why Idea A is not feasible. That teammate will calmly and rationally explain reasons X, Y, and Z for not taking up Idea A and Bob will not accept those reasons. What always proceeds is a 10-60 minute drawn-out conversation/argument eventually leading to Bob letting the topic go and nothing having been improved.

After a few years now of this happening on at least a weekly basis, I'm tired of and frustrated with it. I'd like to let Bob at least feel heard because I don't at all want to discourage ideas for improvement, but I don't want to keep wasting time over things that at face value can be immediately dismissed.

How can I better nip these ideas in the bud when they come up? Or how should I proceed with this type of scenario?

Comment: What would happen if you let Bob try and implement one of his ideas? Would it be beneficial for Bob to see and encounter these reasons on his own?

Comment: Where are these discussions happening? in meetings, hallway chatter, lunch breaks, or someplace else? The tactics for managing the distractions vary depending on the context.

Comment: @MacItaly For some ideas, implementing the idea could be relatively benign (and most of these folks are fine letting him try them out), but for others they could cause some far-reaching security problems, maintenance nightmares, product changes that don't align with business goals, etc.

Comment: @Thunk These discussions happen in our team's area of our open office, so not only are they distracting to the person he's discussing the idea with, but to the immediate teammates near by and all the coworkers in earshot.

Comment: @dabbler I understand. Maybe throwing him a bone with one of the benign ideas could be beneficial. Then when it doesn't pan out you could always reference it. "Bob, don't you remember the [benign] fiasco of 2019?" I sincerely think Bob just wants some validation and to feel like part of the team. You make him seem like a bit of an outcast, a social outlier who doesn't know when to 'stop.' Maybe getting together with your other coworkers and finding ways to validate him, stop him, and then return to work.

Comment: @MacItaly I appreciate the idea, and we essentially already do this with the benign ideas. I'm not a huge fan of the idea of rubbing his nose in his failures. The bigger issue is with the ideas that should be dismissed immediately, but Bob can't let go without a drawn out argument. I don't want to be rude and end a conversation with a simple "No, here are the reasons why, and I'm done talking about this." Perhaps I have to simply accept that these long, distracting arguments are simply the cost of letting a teammate feel validated; but I'm hoping some more elegant solution might be posed here.

Comment: Have you spoken with the team lead about your frustration with these meetings?  Have you considered holding a monthly team meeting to formalize topics like these?

Comment: the answer is "walk out"

Comment: @Fattie Your coworkers must love and adore you...

Comment: They do!  The chance of us having a "useless meeting" is: 0.000000000.  If, for a contract, someone has to attend a Useless Meeting, I take the hit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Informal chats as you described in the comments are harder to manage. At least in a meeting you can reign in the discussion with, “let’s get back to the agenda” kind of thing.

One idea is to establish an informal, completely optional forum, like a lunch brown bag, for open discussions. When one of these ideas come up, redirect it with, “Hey Bob, great idea. Let’s table it for now but you should bring it up in the (witty name for this open chat forum).” Those who are interested can spend their time debating. Those who aren’t can skip it. And if nobody but Bob shows up? Bummer.

Another idea, that I’ve used more successfully, is to put Bob on the hook to follow through: “Interesting idea, Bob. Flesh it out as a proposal, draw up some designs, and make some estimates. Schedule a meeting with (senior team members) and pitch your ideas.” In my experience, odds are good that Bob will never follow through. But, if he does, have him collect the feedback given at the formal review and schedule a follow up to present an amended plan.

This puts all the work on him. If he actually follows through with good ideas, then that’s great. If not, that’s fine too. Should he keep trying to bring it up informally, redirect the discussion with, “oh right. Weren’t you going to schedule a session to present your proposal? When is that meeting again?”

He may well be the type of person that thinks through problems by talking them out with others, so I wouldn’t just shut him down. But I would look for ways to redirect his energy, putting the burden on him and giving you a reason to opt out of the immediate discussion.

Comment: Great ideas -- thank you very much. For some of his ideas (i.e. ones that aren't very feasible because it would take a team 5x the size we have to implement) I have in the past tried to steer him toward following through on them. I'll keep these strategies in mind and try to put them into action.